# Parse an xml document located on the internet and convert to json

Tags: php, xml, json

I found http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/ , but I don't know how to use this code to get the xml from my web server.  any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is with [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents('http://www...../file.xml');
```

If you want a SimpleXML object you can use [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www...../file.xml');
```

Both these methods require [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to be enabled.  If it isn't, you can use [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) - this is more complicated but also gives you more flexibility.

```
$c = curl_init('http://www...../file.xml');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$xmlString = curl_exec($c);
$error = curl_error($c);
curl_close($c);

if ($error)
    die('Error: ' . $error);
```